# Outlook: what variables are available in Quick Steps?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, field-codes

In Outlook (2016) what variables and/or formatting codes are available for use when creating a Quick Step?

For example in *"Forward"* the provided subject line is `FW: <subject>`. I'd like to customize with who the email is from in the subject line, such as `<From.firstname> <From.lastname>: <subject> (<date>)`

[image: Edit Quick Step dialog]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `<subject>` is the only field available.

Comment: Is there anything (like help page or documentation) to support your claim?

Comment: How this doesn't provide the answer? The question is: "what variables are available in Quick Steps?". The answer is: "<subject> is the only field available."

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I am Microsoft Outlook MVP (one of 14 on our Earth). You can trust me.